# Display image on bubble in UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xmppframework

How do I display an image in a `UITableviewCell` when a selection is made from images in the imagepicker (see code sample below) as a message bubble (see screenshot below)?

I am making chat app with XMPPFramework. I have used the implementation from this [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-custom-chat-view-and-emoticons--mobile-7728) to display a speech bubble in a "tableview" cell for receiving and sending messages.

When I select an image or video, I want to display that image like in other chat applications.

Here is code for `UITableviewCell` for row:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSDictionary *s = (NSDictionary *) [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"s:-%@",s);

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MessageCellIdentifier";

SMMessageViewTableCell *cell = (SMMessageViewTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    //cell = [[SMMessageViewTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    cell=[[SMMessageViewTableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSString *sender = [s objectForKey:@"sender"];
NSString *message = [s objectForKey:@"msg"];
//NSString *time = [s objectForKey:@"time"];

CGSize  textSize = { 260.0, 10000.0 };

CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]
                  constrainedToSize:textSize
                      lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

size.width += (padding/2);

cell.messageContentView.text = message;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *bgImage = nil;

if ([sender isEqualToString:@"you"])
{ // left aligned
    bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"aqua.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24  topCapHeight:15];

    [cell.messageContentView setFrame:CGRectMake(360 - size.width - padding,
                                                 padding*2,
                                                 size.width,
                                                 size.height+10)];

    UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(360 - size.width -padding, padding*2, size.width, size.height+10)];
    imgview.image=image;

    [cell.messageContentView addSubview:imgview];


    [cell.bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.x - padding/10,cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.y - padding/10,size.width+padding,size.height+padding)];
}
else
{
    bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"orange.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24  topCapHeight:15];

    [cell.messageContentView setFrame:CGRectMake(padding, padding*2, size.width, size.height+10)];

    [cell.bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.x - padding/10,cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.y - padding/10,size.width+padding,size.height+padding)];
}

cell.bgImageView.image = bgImage;
//cell.senderAndTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", sender, time];
cell.senderAndTimeLabel.text = [self GetDateAndTime];

return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit? I can barely understand what you are really asking. What I understood is, you want to send multimedia e.g. Images in the chat and you want to show it enclosed within the speech bubble? Is that right?

Comment: @NSNoob when i select image from image picker then i want to show that iamge in tableview.

Comment: Are you saying that you are building a messaging app and want to send selected images from one device to another device table view? If yes, then you would want to transfer the image over network and receive it on other device. Once received, save it and reload your table view. Inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` provide provision for loading image from stored images.

Answer (score 0):

In your message object, introduce a flag to determine the message type. Let's say you name it isText. Set it YES for text but Set it NO for media messages (Which you can do in `uiimagepicker` delegate method. Now in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can check the media type. If it is 'NO', you should insert a `uiimageview` as a subview in the cell to display that image. Make sure to leave margins in the bounds of that subview so that it is properly enclosed in the speech bubble. 
To make sure the speech bubble adjusts its own size accordingly, Now you will have to edit your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` Method as well. In the first line your are getting the message object there, Check the flag again. If it is NO, then return height for cell to something like msgImage.frame.size.height+(Top margin to parent view)+ (bottom margin to parentview). Left and right margins will be fixed by centring this imageView to centre of it's parentview i.e. speech bubble.

Comment: Hope this explains the issue you are facing at large. Wish I could write the code for you but I am at work so I can't really. Tie up the lose ends as I must have left behind but this is the main logic which will help you achieve your desired result.

Comment: Correct. For detailed example, refer to this great controller:
[JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController)

Comment: Please do. If it solves your issue, you might want to mark it as the correct answer for helping others who might be facing the same issue. You can also add the coding implementation once you are done.